# Can't load url with android WebView

Tags: android, webview

I am loading some urls in my app using android `WebView` and all successful. But when i am trying to load this url:

> http://dev.infibond.com/cloud/instagram?user_profile=https%3A%2F%2Fscontent.cdninstagram.com%2Ft51.2885-19%2Fs150x150%2F13534190_829691380497090_1099495058_a.jpg&user_name=infibondtest

But for some reason i am failing - "view.loadUrl(url);" in "shouldOverrideUrlLoading" doesn't show the page and doesn't load another url. just shows a white page.
The response code from the server is 304.

Before i am getting to this url, i am doing authentication with Instagram and sending the access token as a cookie.

```
public class CloudWebViewActivity extends ActivityBase {

    public static final String TAG = "WebViewActivity";

    private static final String WEB_VIEW_TOKEN = "token";
    private static final String WEB_VIEW_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String WEB_VIEW_URL = "url";

    private ProgressBar mPbProgress;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private String mTitle, mUrl;

    public static void setInstance(Context context, String title, String url) {
        Intent starter = new Intent(context, CloudWebViewActivity.class);

        starter.putExtra(WEB_VIEW_TITLE, title);
        starter.putExtra(WEB_VIEW_URL, url);

        context.startActivity(starter);
    }

    // MARK: Lifecycle
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTitle = getIntent().getStringExtra(WEB_VIEW_TITLE);
        mUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra(WEB_VIEW_URL);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AppInstance.sharedInstance().getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        AppInstance.sharedInstance().setSelf();
        mToolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
        mPbProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        AppInstance.sharedInstance().getBus().unregister(this);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void findViews() {
        setContentView(R.layout.webview_activity);

        mPbProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pBProgress);

        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        if (mWebView != null) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);

            // Register a new JavaScript interface called HTMLOUT
            mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        }

        if (JavaUtils.isNotNullNotEmptyNotWhiteSpaceOnly(mUrl) && mWebView != null) {
            String cookieString = WEB_VIEW_TOKEN + "=" + NetworkManager.instance().getToken();
            CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(mUrl, cookieString);
            mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
        } else {
            InfiLogger.getInstance().logRemoteException(new RuntimeException("Cloud service: " + mTitle + " came with an empty/null url address"));
            AndroidUtils.showToast(R.string.error_cant_load_url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Toolbar setToolbar() {
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mToolbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            mToolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return mToolbar;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                finish();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void handleProgressBarVisibility(String url) {
        if (url.contains("login") ||
                url.contains("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=") ||
                url.contains("https://vimeo.com/log_in") ||
                url.contains(".jpg")) {
            mPbProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mPbProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private final WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            handleProgressBarVisibility(url);
            String cookieString = WEB_VIEW_TOKEN + "=" + NetworkManager.instance().getToken();
            CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(mUrl, cookieString);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("http://dev.infibond.com/api/cloud/")) {
                mPbProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                // This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished loading.
                view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                AndroidUtils.showToast(error.getDescription());
            } else {
                AndroidUtils.showToast(R.string.gen_Something_went_wrong);
            }
            mPbProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    };

    // An instance of this class will be registered as a JavaScript interface
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @JavascriptInterface
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void processHTML(String html) {
            // process the html as needed by the app
            InfiLogger.d("infi", "html: " + html);

            if (html.contains("code")) {
                final boolean success;
                if (html.contains("\"code\":200")) {
                    AndroidUtils.showToast(AndroidUtils.getString(R.string.cloud_sync_start) + mTitle);
                    success = true;
                } else {
                    AndroidUtils.showToast(AndroidUtils.getString(R.string.gen_Something_went_wrong));
                    success = false;
                }

                AppInstance.sharedInstance().getBus().post(new CloudConnectionStateChangedBusEvent(mTitle, success));
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: get to "view.loadUrl(url);" 
in "shouldOverrideUrlLoading"
but doesn't show the page and doesn't load another url.
just shows a white page.

Comment: That is still not clear. Is the "white page" a finished 200 response from the web server at `dev.infibond.com` or something else? Is the "white page" what you render on an error code response (like a 500, 501?). You need to be much clearer. Suggest updating the question with info.

Comment: the response code is 304. i edited the question. hope its clear now...

Comment: I hope you looked up what a [304 response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) is. It means the content has not changed. Anyway, I posted a possible answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but it seems like you have a lot of small errors. I think the one in question is here:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    handleProgressBarVisibility(url);
    String cookieString = WEB_VIEW_TOKEN + "=" + 
        NetworkManager.instance().getToken();
    CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(mUrl, cookieString);
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

The `view.loadUrl(url)` seems very wrong to me. I think you may need to change this to something like:

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("dev.infibond.com")) {
        return false;
    }
    // otherwise, they are leaving the site, so open a new 
    // browser instead
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    return true;
}
```

And remove the guts of what you did here. Most of it is `findViews()` and should not be repeated anyway. I'm guessing this is what you meant to do with 
`handleProgressBarVisibility(url)` in the `WebViewClient` but I'm not really sure:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
    handleProgressBarVisibility(url);
}
```